Video Player Throws Error When Playing Chunks in Flutter
I'm developing a video player in Flutter that downloads video chunks and plays them without waiting for the entire video to download. However, I'm encountering an issue where the video player throws an error and waits for the full video to be downloaded.
My app should play the video without waiting for full video to get downloaded.
Below are two methods one which fetches data and once which plays:
 Future<void> downloadVideoInChunks(String videoUrl, String videoId) async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    cachedVideoPath = '${tempDir.path}/video_$videoId.mp4';
    cachedFile = File(cachedVideoPath);

    final response = await http.head(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      debugPrint("Failed to get video size: ${response.statusCode}");
      return;
    }

    final totalSize = int.parse(response.headers['content-length']!);
    const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB chunks
    int downloadedBytes = await _loadDownloadedBytes(videoId);
    print("Downloaded bytes: $downloadedBytes}");

    // if(totalSize==_loadDownloadedBytes(videoId)){
    //   print("total size: $totalSize & $downloadedBytes");
    //   playVideoFromCache(videoId);
    // }

    while (downloadedBytes < totalSize) {
      final end = (downloadedBytes + chunkSize - 1).clamp(0, totalSize - 1);
      final rangeHeader = 'bytes=$downloadedBytes-$end';

      final chunkResponse = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(videoUrl),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.rangeHeader: rangeHeader},
      );

      if (chunkResponse.statusCode == 206) { // Partial Content
        await cachedFile.writeAsBytes(chunkResponse.bodyBytes, mode: FileMode.append);
        downloadedBytes += chunkResponse.bodyBytes.length;
        debugPrint("Downloaded $downloadedBytes of $totalSize bytes");

        // Save the progress
        await _saveDownloadedBytes(videoId, downloadedBytes, totalSize);

        // Start playing if enough data has been downloaded
        if (downloadedBytes >= 1024 * 1024) { // Check if at least 1 MB is downloaded
          await playVideoFromCache(videoId);
        }
      } else {
        debugPrint("Failed to download chunk: ${chunkResponse.statusCode}");
        break;
      }
    }
    // if (downloadedBytes >= totalSize) {
    //   await _clearDownloadedBytes(videoId);
    // }
  }
  //
  Future<void> playVideoFromCache(String videoId) async {
    if (await cachedFile.exists()) {
      debugPrint("File exists: ${cachedFile.path}, Size: ${await cachedFile.length()} bytes");
    } else {
      debugPrint("File does not exist: ${cachedFile.path}");
    }
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(cachedFile);
    try {
      if (_videoPlayerController != null) {
        await _videoPlayerController!.initialize();
        await _videoPlayerController!.play();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("playVideoFromCache: ${e.toString()}");
    }
  }

Erorr
Downloaded 1048576 of 43215033 bytes
W/.example.m_yoga( 4149): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/CompatChangeReporter( 4149): Compat change id reported: 236825255; UID 10211; state: ENABLED
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):   androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:736)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:708)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:85)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):   Caused by: androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:125)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:275)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1045)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:421)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4149):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
I/flutter ( 4149): playVideoFromCache: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)

